# Puzzle about phographers in Africa taking pictures of 2 Animals which name corresponds to last name of their friends

Tags: puzzle

Leo Lion, Tom Tiger, Eddie Elephant, George Gazelle, Peter Panther, Luke Leopard were on photographic safari in Africa. 
Every photographer took a picture of 2 animals. Every of these 2 animals belonged to spiecies corresponding to last names of photographer's friends .
Every animal was was pictured by exacly two 2 photographers.

Also:

- Every photographer took picture of at least one animal which is cat
- Eddie and George summed up photographed all 4 cats family animals
- George and Peter took picture of Leopard
- Both namesakes of the animals that Eddie photographed, photographed gazelle
- Tom didn't pictured any of animals that Peter photographed
- George and Tom pictured the same animal

---

I tried solve this and rewrote the additional information

- Every photographer took picture of at least one animal which is cat
- Elephant and Gazelle summed up photographed all 4 cat's family animals
- Gazelle and Panthera took picture of leopard
  -Both namesakes of the animals that Elephant photographed, photographed gazelle
- Tiger didn't pictured any of animals that Panthera photographed
- Gazelle and Tiger pictured the same animal

and then I only found out this:

LION - > ....

TIGER -> gazelle

ELEPHANT -> tiger

GAZELLE -> leopard

PANTHER -> leopard

LEOPARD -> ...

Not homework.. I try to prepare myself.

Comment: Should the 4'th constraint be "Both namesakes of the animals that Eddie photographed, photographed gazelle"?

Comment: @RenéB.Christensen Yes you are right I have made a mistake during translation.

Comment: @RenéB.Christensen Any ideas I don't know method how to solve this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table with the possible combination, and cross out or put a plus in each cell to indicate whether this combination is possible or not. Because each photographer takes pictures of two animals, each row and column must contain two plusses. For example, using the information *"George and Peter took picture of Leopard"*, our table would be:

[image: Table of possibilities]

Continuing to add the other information, this table would eventually be filled out, and the solution can be read off (spoiler):

> [image]

Comment: How do we know that George and Tom photographed panther not other cat? Everything beside that I understand.

Comment: @Yoda: It isn't something you can easily deduce directly, but as more and more cells are being filled, you will discover these combinations.